# Wordpress not redirecting properly (Forbidden)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

At some point I changed my Wordpress URL under Settings -> General. This created a lot of problems that are mostly fixed. However, my site's Url is "example.com/guiacentros/" and that works, but when users wrote "example.com" it also used to work, and now they get a "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server". Is this an error with the htacces file? This is the current htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /guiacentros/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /guiacentros/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm a bit confused because there's a second htaccess file one level above, that looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm not sure why there's two, but I remember adding the second one fixed some issues.

Comment: You should provide more details, such as are you installing WordPress in a subdirectory of the vhost document root. What was the old url you used? You can try saving your permalinks settings again.

Comment: Is this an error with the htacces file? The answer is NO. It is depends on how you setup your document root in your server, where you installed your WordPress, and your settings in WordPress Settings->General->WordPress Address (URL) and Settings->General->Site Address (URL)

Comment: My Wordpress is installed inside html -> guiacentros. Then inside of Settings -> General, both the Wordpress and the Home URL are set to be "http://example.com/guiacentros". ideally, the home would be simply "example.com" and that would redirect to "example.com/guiacentros", but if I change it I get the "forbidden" error.

Comment: You still haven't answered the most important question of what your document root is for this site.

Comment: The root is "example.com/guiacentros" as it is installed in a subfolder.

Comment: ... can you paste the exact VirtualHost document root path here. Does it point to ../example.com or ./example.com/guiacentros? See this link, there's a difference between installing it the subfolder at first or the root folder and moving it later :https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory